# If Statement inside or outside

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out if I need to do this inside the for loop or outside the for loop but I want to check to see its empty or not first.

```
echo "<ul>";
for($x = 0; $x <= (count($quotesArray)-1); $x++)
{
    echo "<li>".stripslashes($quotesArray[$x]->quote)."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: You want to check what is empty? `$quotesArray`, or `$quotesArray[$x]->quote`?

Comment: You really should use a `foreach` instead: `foreach ($quotesArray as $quote)`

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It's not clear 'exactly' what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also: what is your version of PHP? Is it greater than 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **something simpler** that checking during loop - it **filters all the values** and is called [`array_filter()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$quotesArray = array_filter($quotesArray);
echo "<ul>";
foreach($quotesArray as $quote){
    echo "<li>".stripslashes($quote)."</li>";
};
echo "</ul>";
```

The above assumes that `$quotesArray` contains strings (or elements that work correctly in string context) and you do not want only the elements that are evaluated as `false` when converted to boolean ([see more about converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)).

Additionally **you can simplify your code further**:

```
$quotesArray = array_filter($quotesArray);
$quotesArray = array_map('stripslashes', $quotesArray);
echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $quotesArray).'</li></ul>';
```

if you know `$quotesArray` contains at least one element.

**EDIT:**

Short version, that also **checks whether the list should be generated** (in other words: whether array contains at least one element after processing):

```
$quotesArray = array_map('stripslashes', array_filter($quotesArray));
if (!empty($quotesArray)) {
    echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $quotesArray).'</li></ul>';
};
```

Comment: @JeffDavidson: I am not sure what you mean, but if you meant that you want it to not generate any HTML if array is empty, then please see my updated answer - it now should not generated anything if array is empty after processing.

Comment: Ouch, my reputation. Very slick solution though - definitely plan on using this.

Comment: @cantera25: Thanks. Such code can be even "slicker" when PHP version is at least _5.3_ thanks to the ability to use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and pass them as callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be outside the loop because if it is empty, and you don't generate any list items, then you have no list, so you should not generate the ul start and end tags either (since a list with no list items is invalid).

Comment: Unless what he wants to check is if the items are empty. Then it goes inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

well if you dont wan the list at all then you should do it before the echoing of the first `<ul>`

```
if(count($quotesArray) > 0){
//Do your echos and loops in here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just run both checks.

```
if($quotesArray){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($quotesArray as $quote) {
        if ($quote) {
            echo '<li>' . stripslashes($quote->quote) . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure those <ul> tags need to go inside the conditional, or does php/html know to ignore them?

Comment: You're right for the sake of bandwidth consumption and the overall structure of the markup.  But, <ul> tags on their own don't render anything unless styled to do so.  Good catch though. I've edited my answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to check if it's empty, do you mean the entire $quotesArray or one of the values within it?

If you mean you want to check if a value within the array is empty, you could consider this approach:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($quotesArray as $quote) {
    if ($quote) {
        echo '<li>' . stripslashes($quote) . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: you dont need the `$key` there it actually takes up more memory and is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks - glad to know I was doing it incorrectly, thought the separation was needed. Does the edited version look correct?